# Magento 2.2.2 error: The configuration file has changed. Run app:config:import or setup:upgrade command to synchronize configuration

Tags: php, magento, config, magento2

I am getting this error when attempting to install Magento locally:

> The configuration file has changed. Run app:config:import or
>   setup:upgrade command to synchronize configuration.

When running "app:config:import" nothing is resolved, when running "setup:upgrade" it runs and then fails towards the end with the following reason:

> Import failed: Hash has not been saved.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I am running in my local environment in "Default" mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this is a fresh install.

If it is, try to skip the `app:config:import` command as you won't have a config to import as of yet..

If it is not a fresh install, check:

- app/etc/env.php has the right permissions and credentials inside it
- app/etc/config.php has all the extensions/modules listed correctly and permissions are correct

Comment: So just to add some more context to these errors. I have a production site on Magento Cloud and a local setup with a database set up on AWS.  I ended up replacing my local AWS database with a fresh copy from the production site and this fixed the issue.  Also, running Magento locally in production mode also suppressed the error.  I guess the AWS and production databases were just too out of sync. Thank you for your answer though Giolliano.

Comment: Ah glad you got it fixed. Most likely there were modules in setup_module that were a bit too behind and it was expecting it to be in the config.php!